# Yang - Implementing order dependent CLIs

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have two CLIs and I have this below requirement.

If #1 is configured first, then #2 config is NOT allowed.
If #2 is configured first, then #1 config is allowed.

I have tried using must, but that makes them mutually exclusive. How do I implement this ordering in Yang?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of #1 and #2 and what you are trying to achieve here? How does your CLI change the configuration, what are the commands for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct approach available with this in Yang. May be for your product you need to add an extension, which can check while config is being loaded as part of edit-config